# Custom soap header with asmx web service

Tags: c#, soap, asmx, soapheader

My WebService (simplified)

```
public class ContactService : WebService
 {
    public AuthenticationHeader AuthenticationInformation;

    public class AuthenticationHeader : SoapHeader
    {
        public string Token;
    }
}
```

My Client (simplified)

```
var temp = new ContactServiceSoapClient();
temp.AuthenticationInformation//<-- is not there
```

I can examine the reference.cs file and see that my client does have the AuthenticationHeader class, it is just not available as a property of my soap client.

Why does my soap client not have an AuthenticationHeader property?

I am using VS 2013 add/update service reference on my client.

Comment: That's now how SOAP Headers work in a WCF client. Look at the operations of the service. They will have the headers.

Comment: sorry, how do I find these operations?

Comment: One convenient way is to use the Object Browser to look at the client type (`ContactServiceSoapClient`)